# How to upload obj with mtl and textures to bucket?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

As the title suggests, how do I upload the obj model's material file and textures, as they are hard coded in the obj file.

Can I upload zipped dir structure or multiple files that are in correct relation (because of the hard coded nature of obj)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an OBJ model with material and texture on the dotty trial site:

http://trial.dotdotty.com/share/?shareId=cdc9-523f-305f-7ddb-5cc4

That was uploaded as a single zip file containing OBJ, MTL and PNG.

Here is the same model on A360:

http://a360.co/21rt4OK

That was uploaded by selecting all three files and specifying the OBJ as the main model.

Comment: so i just upload to the bucket a single zip. is it extracted on oss?

Comment: try it out and let us know how it goes, please. it is either that or upload the three and specify references from the OBJ to the other two.

Answer (score 0):

A .ZIP file should work for Autodesk Model Derivative as long as the same works locally (meaning all references are working).