# Forge Viewer: material/texture not showing

Tags: 3dsmax, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am uploading an .obj file into my Forge Viewer app, but when it loads in the viewer the material/textures are gone, leaving the model grey. How can I keep the materials/textures or what should I do to apply this the correct way?

Comment: Can I upload my png textures and my obj model in a zip? I tried this with no luck.

Comment: I am also having a similar question, however, my question is relative to a FBX file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obj with MTL or PNG textures should be packaged in a zip file before uploading to OSS. Here is the reference:
[How to upload obj with mtl and textures to bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37912099/how-to-upload-obj-with-mtl-and-textures-to-bucket/37929809#37929809)

Comment: I have experienced that SketchUp files also works. Is there any other format than OBJ and SketchUp file format that will show textures/materials?