# Is there a way to upload obj and mtl file at once with textures

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

As the question says, I have an `obj` file and an `mtl` file with the texture details and I would like to upload an obj file with texture on mtl file in Forge Viewer so that it would display the model with texture.

I found a solution, which says that making a zip out of `mtl`, `obj` and `png` file will be uploaded to the Forge Viewer but when I tried it was not uploading. Is there a way to add texture in `mtl` file to `obj` file?

A link to the solution I was talking about is given below:

[How to upload obj with mtl and textures to bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37912099/how-to-upload-obj-with-mtl-and-textures-to-bucket)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few requirements for translating OBJ with MTL textures:

1. The texture files should be put along with the OBJ and MTL file, i.e. all files should be placed in the same level of the directory.
2. The path marked in the MTL file should reflect the 1st.
3. Pack all files of the texture, MTL, and OBJ into a single ZIP archive.
4. No folder in the ZIP file.
5. Make sure the `rootFilename` is pointing to the OBJ, and `compressedUrn` is true while triggering Forge translation job.

Hope it helps.